# applying a 20% discount for students to magento store

Tags: magento

I am trying to apply a student discount to some of my products but I can only see a way of applying a discount to the product itself, so everyone gets the discount!  What I really want is somewhere for students to enter a code to get their discount, how can I achieve this please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: how magnanimous of you, sorry for making a mistake, I guess you have never made any mistakes!

Comment: Please don't be rude. I was very polite. Stack Overflow has a higher level of professionalism than many other forum sites. It is expected that everyone will be frank and respectful with each other.

Comment: I found your initial statement very patronising, I responded accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a discount with coupon code, you should create a shopping cart price rule. So the students can add the products to cart and enter the coupon code on shopping cart page to get the discount for the products.

1. In Magento backend go to Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules.
2. Click Add New Rule on the top right.
3. Complete all required options. Set Coupon field to Specific Coupon and enter a coupon code on below text field. On conditions tab, configure settings for discount products that should be found in cart. On actions tab, configure setting to apply rules only for discounted product.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have successfully applied the discount.

Comment: Great to hear! Please mark this answer as correct answer for others with the same question.